# Prove that two grayscale images are same or not

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

[image]

Given two grayscale images represented by two matrices where each cell indicates the pixel value (shown in the picture). How can I determine whether the two images are the same or not? On looking at the grayscale values, it is clear that the second image is the rotated version of the first one. But is there a mathematical proof or way to show it?

**My approach**: We can create histograms for both the images and match them. If they don't match, then the images are not the same. But the problem is that histograms don't show the spatial characteristics of the images. There may be two images with the same histograms but are actually totally different from each other.

Comment: The two images are neither rotated nor mirror images of each other. They are not "the same".

Comment: Can you upload the image values in textual form? It's kind of a pain for people trying to answer you to retype all the values manually.

Comment: Use `np.array_equal(imA,imB)` to test if all elements are equal. Flip per Rahul's answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two compare 2 images of the same orientation, use this:

```
diff = np.subtract(img1, img2)
if np.sum(diff != 0) > 0:
    print("Images are not same")
else:
    print("Images are same")
```

Now flip one of the images once wrt horizontal axis, and then wrt verticle axis(and also transpose the image once(if that is a case)) and compare these images one by one with the second image. If any of these images are the same, then the 2 images are same else they are not the same.

Instead of flipping, you can use rotate(keep in mind that you rotate by 180 degrees).
[See this to know how to flip and rotate](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-numpy-rotate-flip/)

Comment: They are in the question.

Comment: Sorry, there was a big misunderstanding. Of course pixel-wise comparison works.

Comment: This is itself the image or the matrix inside the image is the grayscale image? I think the second one is right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here, the question has been edited.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I am not actually summing up the values of the diff image. By `np.sum(diff != 0)`, I am counting the number of values in the diff image that are not `0`. Thus, in your case also, If condition will become true and the code will say that images are not the same. In your case, `np.sum(diff != 0) = 2`.

Comment: I see, sorry. I shall delete my comment so as not to mislead others in my foolish ways